# Volume of oblique cylinder

Tags: geometry

In my homework, was given an oblique cylinder with a radius of 3, slant height of 6, a slant angle of 60 degrees. I do not understand how to find volume of slanted cylinders. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oblique cylinders have the same height as regular cylinders in terms of $r$ and $h$! To convince yourself, try [this](http://www.mathopenref.com/common/appletframe.html?applet=cylinderoblique&wid=600&ht=350), and you'll see that an oblique cylinder is just a warped right cylinder.

So if the slant angle is $60$ degrees, the height is $3\sqrt{3}$ by the $30-60-90$ triangle properties. So then the volume is $\pi r^2 h=\pi (9)^2(3 \sqrt{3})=243\sqrt{3} \pi$

Comment: "Oblique cylinders have the same height as regular cylinders in terms of r and h!" I totally forgot about that!!! My high school teacher talked about this in class and she says "pretend the cylinders are vertical, but beware of the information they give you" (in regards to height or slant height)

Comment: Yup! Make sure you don't get them confused!

Comment: Imagine that you have a tall stack of thin coins (say, if you're an American, dimes) and decide to make it lean over a bit by sliding the coins horizontally.  This is an example of what is referred to as "Cavalieri's Principle".  By the way, you're not limited to just making the cylinder oblique:  you can twist and bend the cylinder any way you like along its height, as long as the cross-sections at each "level" are unchanged.

Comment: I really like that!